# ANDROID adapter in a spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a little question about the use of spinners and adapter, i would like to search all the file in a directory and put the file's name in a spinner.
this is my code :

```
File repertoire = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/androidtest/vente")  ;


    String[] tabFile = repertoire.list();

    if (tabFile==null){

        Log.d("file null","testdfed");  
    }
    Log.d("//","///////////");
    for (int i = 0; i < tabFile.length; i++) {
        Log.d("Tableau",tabFile[i].toString());
    }

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<tabFile.length; i++) {
        list.add(tabFile[i]);

    }

//for checking in the logcat if my code have found all the files        
   for (String s : list) {

       Log.d("Liste",s);
   }


//creation of the adapter   
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

//finally the listener
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        int item = sp.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "You have selected 222 : " + item,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
});
```

My code crash at sp.setAdapter(adapter);
Thanks you ! :)

I'm new in SOF sso i have to edit my text:
For the answer of Mukesh Kumar
already done,i initialise before  onCreate

```
public class OfflineActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinm);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

so i replace like you would

```
public class OfflineActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private Spinner sp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
    sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinm);
```

bu my code crash for the same reason :/

Comment: please show the error logs

Comment: post logcat error messages.

Comment: 05-07 12:00:03.731: E/Trace(6236): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score 0):

As you told `My code crash at sp.setAdapter(adapter);`

It may be you have not initialised `sp`, . First initialise it befor use. i.e.
In `onCreate()` of your `Activity` write this code.

```
sp= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_id_in_your_xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will works for a spinner

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Android");
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Spinner Data");
    list.add("Spinner Adapter");
    list.add("Spinner Example");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: same way , this code don't crash for me if i comment:
    //spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you are passing the fragment instead of the context try replacing `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);`

with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Comment: another error : getActivity() undifined in the class OfflineActivity // my main class